Excel vlookup oddity
I have a simple table with rows Low, Medium, High.
I’m trying to use a VLOOKUP to see the value associated with that but I get #N/A when searching for the value High. Only high fails to look up. Anything I’m missing?
=VLOOKUP(D7,A1:B3,2)


Are you sure A3=D7? Check for trailing spaces. Next, you should use last argument FALSE in VLOOKUP. The second is a more probable reason.

Values are the same. The False argument was the key. Doh.

Still unsure why it would need that though…….

It probably should be:
=VLOOKUP(D7,A1:B3,2,FALSE)


Indeed that solved it but why?

The 4th parameter of VLOOKUP is optional. Its default value is TRUE. We need it to be FALSE because we need exact match. To use approximate match option data in the table should be sorted A-Z.

you need to add 4th argument too: =VLOOKUP(D7, A1:B3, 2, FALSE)
for the last argument:

range_lookup   (optional)
A logical value that specifies whether you want VLOOKUP to find an
approximate or an exact match:

Approximate match - 1/TRUE assumes the first column in the table is
sorted either numerically or alphabetically, and will then search for
the closest value. This is the default method if you don't specify
one. For example, =VLOOKUP(90,A1:B100,2,TRUE).

Exact match - 0/FALSE searches for the exact value in the first
column. For example, =VLOOKUP("Smith",A1:B100,2,FALSE).



https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1
